# Queue Resize method

Tags: java

I am writing a priority queue code using arrays. I would like to create a method that change the size of the queue and extends the size of the queue when the queue is filled over the 75%. Can anyone help?

here is my method:

```
public void insert(T object) {
    if (object == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (size == heap.length - 1) throw new IllegalStateException();

    heap[++size] = object;

    swim(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public void insert(T object) {
    if (object == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (size >= 0.75*heap.length) {
        resize(2*heap.length);
    }

    heap[++size] = object;
}

private void resize(int newSize) {
    T[] newHeap = (T[])new Object[newSize];
    System.arraycopy(heap, 0, newHeap, 0, size);
    heap = newHeap;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `T[] newHeap = new T[newSize];` ?

Comment: The `newHeap` array should be of type T. It should be `T[] newHeap = (T[])new Object[newSize];` The compiler will complain that there is an unchecked cast. You can tell it to stop complaining with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. This is reasonable because you know it will hold elements of Type T.

Comment: I assumed that T was a generic type, and in that case, arrays of T cannot be created.

Comment: I also assumed that T was generic. If the backing array is of type Object then client code needs to do the cast. Just make the cast in the API code and tell the compiler it is ok. This simplifies client code.

Comment: I disagree: if heap is of type T[], you cannot assign it a Object[].

Comment: I never said you could do that my comment clearly uses a cast before the assignment.